# WordPress Staging to Live

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I find it so weird that Wordpress doesn't have any standard procedure for releasing specific notes from staging to live.

**I am searching for a plugin that can push specific pages or posts, not the entire DB.**

As a developer I can push files using git and execute sql queries for DB but this is not possible for translators and content managers.

Comment: You can save a post/page as draft if you don't want to publish it .

Comment: Thats a good idea, but what happens if a page is already published and on staging there are some unfinished changes. and I want to push another page live.

Comment: Your idea of having a data migration is not available in WP . You just cant 'push' pages/posts from local machine to live one .